# powershell - remove string containing line breaks and spaces

Tags: string, powershell, replace, powershell-2.0

I have a script running in powershell (v2), that removes strings from a file.

The basic process is:

```
(Get-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename1) -replace 'longString', 'shortString' | ` 
Set-Content $cfg_Local_Dir\$filename1

Get-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename1 | `
            Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'stringToMatch'} | `
            Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'secondStringToMatch'} | `
            Set-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename
```

This works fine. However, I have an annoying string that I can't get rid of.

It basically consists of: a line break and carriage return, 4 spaces, and then a line break and carriage return. In HEX it is `0D 0A 20 20 20 20 0D 0A`

How can I remove this?

I tried simply:

```
Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '    '} #4 x spaces
```

But that removed all content after that line (and this is on the second line).

I looked at:

```
Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '$([char]0x0D)'}
```

(I would have expanded it if it had removed all the Carriage Returns) which I saw in another post somewhere, but that did nothing.

What is the correct way of dealing with this problem?

---

Additional: 2015-11-24 13:49

Example Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<start_of_data>
        <job>123456</job>
        <name>ABC123</name>
        <start></start> 
</start_of_data> 
<start_of_data>
        <job>789012</job>
        <name>DEF345</name>
        <start></start> 
</start_of_data>
```

Initially there is a string on line 2 which is removed by 'stringToMatch', and the spaces are on line3.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "$([char]0x0D)"}` with double-quotes, to expand the variable ?

Comment: thanks for that, I am forever getting my quotes wrong - (I should just learn to automatically change my quotes whenever I have a problem). . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things worth pointing out here. When you use `-match`/`-notmatch` you are using regex. We can consolidate your strings and space issue into one string.

```
Get-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename1 | 
    Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'stringToMatch|secondStringToMatch|\s{4,}'} | 
    Set-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename
```

That works using alternation to match either element separated by pipes. This is by no means perfect as we don't have sample data to work with but if you have lines with either of those two string or at least 4 consecutive spaces they will be omitted.

From talking in the comments and looking at the example file you are just trying to omit lines that are blank. Using another string class or regex could fix that. These lines function differently but would both ignore lines that are just white-space.

- `![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)`
- `-notmatch ^\s+$`

I will op'd for the former as it is more intuitive.

```
Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -and $_ -notmatch 'stringToMatch|secondStringToMatch'}
```

Like I said in comments if you are picky on this requirement that you could filter out lines with exactly 4 white-space characters with `-notmatch ^\s{4}$`

---

Also like [sodawillow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677139/sodawillow) says you should have used double quotes to allow variable expansion. Since you are using regex `\r` would have worked just as well.

```
Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "$([char]0x0D)"}
```

However I don't *think* you would have seen that character anyway in order to exclude it. `Get-Content` would scrub that out to make a string array. That might depend on encoding.

Comment: cheers for the point about consolidating the strings. I tried using double quotes but it made no difference and my (xml) file still had the 0x0D characters in when I looked at it in the HEX editor. When I ran `Get-Content $Local_Dir1\$filename1` It displays the contents of the file, and there is a line with spaces on the second line. (I also realised why all my lines dissapeared when I used \s{4} - most of my lines have 6 spaces at the start!!! )

Comment: @IGGt If it is _exactly_ 4 spaces then you could use boundaries `\b\s{4}\b` instead of `\s{4,}` should fix that. That way it won't match the 6 spaces. There are nicer and neater ways to do this but that keeps with my alternation example.

Comment: cheers, I tried it as `where-Object {$_ -notmatch '\b\s{4,}\b'}` but still no luck the line remains, And when I open the file in the HEX editor it still says  `20 20 20 20 0D 0A` for that line.

Comment: @IGGt Hmm. Can you host a copy of the file that has that line in it? I understand there might be sensitive data there so please scrub that out.  Also you can try this instead maybe `$_ -notmatch '^\s{4}$'`

Comment: You are a star!! that has got it. I was about to start playing around with removing line 2 each time - which wouldn't have been the best way to go...

Comment: If that worked then there are a bunch of things that could fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Try .Net **String** class:

```
Where-Object {-not[string]::IsNullOrEmpty(([string]$_).trim())}
```

`Trim` will remove spaces and `IsNullOrEmpty` will check the rest.

Comment: cheers, but it just resulted in a blank file - maybe because I realised most of my lines start with multiple blank spaces!!)